# How to listen for job progress in Spark without Spark Rest API

Tags: apache-spark

I have created my own spark listener class that extends SparkListener. I have overrided the methods onJobStart and onJobEnd. But can't find a way to get job progress. I want to see the percentage of the job that is complete. I know I can get through Spark Rest API, but unfortunately I can't use that. Is there any other way I can get job progress percentage?

Comment: Hi, can you share your spark listener implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every job consists of stages, so job start event has stageInfos. Every stage has numTasks, so potentially you can count how many tasks are there in total, and with listening on onTaskEnd/onStageCompleted you can follow job progress.